# ROS Answers SE migration: explore stack

Tags: ros, gazebo, simulation, exploration

[image: Rosanswers logo]

hi, i am trying to use the explore stack in gazebo, but i get the following warnings:

```
[ WARN] [1342514709.419049768, 713.848000000]: Costmap2DROS transform timeout. Current time: 713.8480, global_pose stamp: 713.5130, tolerance: 0.3000
[ WARN] [1342514708.892588284, 711.502000000]: Map update loop missed its desired rate of 5.0000Hz... the loop actually took 0.2230 seconds
```

i dont't find a doku about the explore stack just the examples...can anyone help me ?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/38984/explore-stack/) by [pkohout](https://answers.ros.org/users/2803/pkohout/) on ROS Answers with karma: 336 on 2012-07-16

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [salma](https://answers.ros.org/users/3271/salma/) on 2013-04-21**:
please can you tell me how you used explore stack in gazebo ?

**Comment by [salma](https://answers.ros.org/users/3271/salma/) on 2013-04-21**:
i tried it ,it begin to draw the map, but it didn't move on rviz without teleop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

you have to change tranform tolerance, set it to something like 0.5
and you have to decrease update_frequency in global costmap params and local costmap params. it is  stated to have them same in navigation tuning wiki

---

Originally posted by [cagatay](https://answers.ros.org/users/2526/cagatay/) with karma: 1850 on 2012-07-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [pkohout](https://answers.ros.org/users/2803/pkohout/) on 2012-07-17**:
ok thanks, the warning are now gone. but i have still a problem, i dont publish anything on the slam_entropy topic, which pkg publishes there something ? do you have some advise ?

**Comment by [cagatay](https://answers.ros.org/users/2526/cagatay/) on 2012-07-17**:
gmapping publsihes entropy, maybe slam_entropy can be remapped type of it

**Comment by [pkohout](https://answers.ros.org/users/2803/pkohout/) on 2012-07-17**:
remapping works, the explore nodes subscribes it...but still nothing happens.... did i have to call a service or so that the explore node starts exploring or so ??

**Comment by [cagatay](https://answers.ros.org/users/2526/cagatay/) on 2012-07-19**:
yes it can subscribe it but is remapped topic  being published ?

**Comment by [pkohout](https://answers.ros.org/users/2803/pkohout/) on 2012-07-19**:
nope remapped topic does not publish anything ://

**Comment by [pkohout](https://answers.ros.org/users/2803/pkohout/) on 2012-07-23**:
now it all get published and subscribed, but i get the following info after starting exploration:Done exploring with 0 goals left that could not be reached. There are 0 goals on our blacklist, and 0 of the frontier goals are too close to them to pursue. The rest had global planning fail to them.

**Comment by [pkohout](https://answers.ros.org/users/2803/pkohout/) on 2012-07-23**:
exploration complete .... do you have any ideas ?